# Is a canal a type of river?

Tags: synonyms

A Chinese friend of mine says that in Chinese there are no different words for canal and river, and that they are the treated as the same noun. A canal would be a man-made river if you had to distinguish. In English I think they are distinct terms and that they are both types of waterway, if I wanted a generic term.

So am I right in thinking that a canal is not a type of river?

Comment: While the existing answers are correct about the technical uses of these words, I would like to point out that if a native English speaker came across a canal but did not know it was artificial they would likely call it a river, a stream, or a creek because these are words for waterways. 'Waterway' is more technical and not really common speech.

Comment: But the question is quite simple: Is a canal a type of river? No, it isn't. Yes it is _like_ a river. A mouse is _like_ a rat, but it isn't a _type_ of rat, nor does its similarity automatically extend the definition of 'rat' to include 'mouse'. I don't see how providing obscure examples of hybrid river-canals, fjords that happen to have 'Canal' in the name, actually answer the OP's question. (Although they are interesting :) )

Comment: @called2voyage: It's common speech in the name of the Woodlands Waterway in The Woodlands, TX.  That's probably because it has an alliterative appeal that "canal" doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

A **canal** is a man-made waterway. You are right in thinking that a canal is *not* a type of river in English. A river (in this sense) is a *natural* waterway, and ***waterway*** is a useful generic term to use to describe these kind of features, whether they are man-made or not.

From the [OED, in sense 6a](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/26882?rskey=SkTMG7&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (which I think is most appropriate to the original question):

> **canal, n.** *An artificial watercourse constructed to unite rivers, lakes, or seas, and serve the purposes of inland navigation. (The chief modern sense, which tends to influence all the others.)*

Comment: One minor caveat: there's an admittedly rare overlap because natural rivers can be "canalised". The canalised section of the River Lea which flows through London near my house is often referred to as a canal, at least for that section, but is also still the River Lea. So IMO a canal can, if rarely, be a type of river.

Comment: Good point, there are examples of hybrid canal-rivers, but in general, I still wouldn't consider the definition of a canal to be a _type_ of river. Though all three (rivers, canals, canalised-rivers) could be considered _waterways_ in this sense.

Comment: Not always manmade. [Hood Canal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hood_Canal), in Washington State, **looks** like a man-made waterway on a map, but it's actually a natural salt-water extension of Puget Sound, filling a deep glaciated valley, rather like the Finger Lakes of New York State.

Comment: No, I would still assert that canals are _man-made_, _artificial_ waterways. Any dictionary will give you a similar definition. Just because a natural feature _looks_ artificial, or even has a name to suggest otherwise, doesn't change the fact that is a natural feature. Hood Canal is not a canal, it's a fjord, despite its misleading name. The [_Old Man of Coniston_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_of_Coniston), a mountain in England, is not actually an old man, but its craggy appearance resembles one in some people's eyes.

Comment: While @Rupe is correct regarding canalised rivers, these are usually known as a "Navigation", in Britain at least.  You have the Lea Navigation, the Trent Navigation and so on.  This is normally the case where locks have been placed on a natural river to make it navigable.

Comment: I didn't see @JohnLawler's comment before I posted my answer to this question.

Comment: @John Lawler One could argue that Hood Canal isn't a canal in the same way that John Smith isn't a smith.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, a Smith could happen to be a smith. It appears that certain explorers considered the term *canal* to include certain kinds of natural waterways. The term is obviously related to *channel*, which is agnostic as to whether it was formed by man or nature; I'd not be surprised to learn that *canal* used to be as similarly agnostic as *channel* is today.

Comment: @ Cyberherbalist I'd certainly answer 'No' to 'Is Hood Canal a canal?' (though if the questioner were genuine, I'd go into more detail).

Comment: More misnamed examples: the [Old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Bedford_River) and [New Bedford Rivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Bedford_River) are canals, not rivers. (And nowhere near Bedford.)

Comment: I love the aside given by OED ('The chief modern sense, which tends to influence all the others.') I'd take this as a requirement to define terms if any sense other than this were being used (except in highly specific and understood contexts, eg Mars).

Comment: @Gareth Rees +1 for your bold oxymorons.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, and (perhaps naively) I assumed the original question was about canals in the "chief modern sense", as opposed to North-American fjords, root canal treatment, [the Canal of Nuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canal_of_Nuck), [Schlemm's Canal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemm%27s_canal), or [Canaletto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canaletto).

Comment: @Chenmunka  Yes, "navigation" may be the official term but locally (I'm 5 minutes walk away as I type) people would talk about "going down the canal" or "...river" interchangeably. I've never heard anyone refer to it as "the navigation".

Answer (score 8):

Their main difference of 'artificial waterway' vs 'natural waterway' is clear from their etymology. Actually canal comes from Latin "canna" (reed).

[Canal](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Canal&searchmode=none):

> early 15c., from French canal, chanel "water channel, tube, pipe, gutter" (12c.), from Latin canalis *"water pipe, groove, channel,"* noun use of adjective from canna "reed" (see cane (n.)). Originally in English "a pipe for liquid," its sense transferred by 1670s to "artificial waterway."

[River](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=River&searchmode=none):

> early 13c., from Anglo-French rivere, Old French riviere "river, riverside, river bank" (12c.), from Vulgar Latin *riparia "riverbank, seashore, river" (source also of Spanish ribera, Italian riviera), noun use of fem. of Latin riparius "of a riverbank" (see riparian). Generalized sense of "a copious flow" of anything is from late 14c. The Old English word was ea "river," cognate with Gothic ahwa, Latin aqua (see aqua-). Romanic cognate words tend to retain the sense "river bank" as the main one, or else the secondary Latin sense "coast of the sea" (compare Riviera).

Suorce: http://www.etymonline.com/

Comment: You may be dismayed to discover that there are several fjords on the northwest coast of North America which have "canal" in their names.  See my answer.

Comment: At risk of invoking Muphry, you misspelled the word *Source*.

Answer (score 4):

Specifically to add a note of discordance to the otherwise useful distinction of river and canal as natural vs manmade waterways, I submit for your perplexity a natural waterway near my place of residence.  It is called [Hood Canal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hood_Canal).  It is a fjord that was formed about 13,000 years ago by the Puget lobe of the Cordilleran Ice Sheet.

[image]

In fact, it is not the only natural waterway named "canal".  There are several other examples in North America:

- Behm Canal, U.S. state of Alaska
- Gardner Canal, British Columbia, Canada
- Lynn Canal, U.S. state of Alaska
- Pearse Canal, part of the Canada-United States border at Alaska
- Portland Canal, British Columbia, Canada

So, one must include in the category *canal*: a natural fjord.

Comment: Not necessarily. Misnomers are well known. The creature called a 'king crab' is not even a crustacean, never mind a crab. A peanut is not a nut. Mincemeat usually contains no meat. Why should we insist that Hood Canal (Casiquiaire Canal etc) be true canals?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I grant you the possibility of a misnomer X 6.  Perhaps they were all named by the same explorer?  I would never give the descriptor canal to a natural waterway, but I live in 2014.  My suggestion in my comment to decvalt's answer is that at one time canal and channel were equivalent, and hence are agnostic as to whether natural or manmade.  I'm probably wrong, however.  Giovanni Schiaparelli's description of the *canali* of Mars, which was translated into English as *canals* led many to assume Schiaparelli had described artificial structures when he had not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, as to mincemeat not containing any meat, I would point out that the word *meat* has only recently taken on the exclusive meaning of *flesh*.  At one time *meat* was a generic term for foodstuff, and mincemeat was not at all a misnomer. Sorry, but I must correct you about king crab, too.  While not a crab, a king crab is nevertheless a crustacean.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_crab

Comment: (1) Misnomers often result from semantic shift (ie this subset weren't always misnomers, but they are now). There is no necessary implication that the term was in any way erroneous. [see the excellent Wikipedia article.] (2) For 'the creature called' please read 'one creature sometimes called': The Atlantic horseshoe crab, Limulus polyphemus, is a marine chelicerate ... The term "king crab" is sometimes used for horseshoe crabs ... ( [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_horseshoe_crab) ).

Comment: Wow, didn't know that about horseshoe crabs! Can't see why anyone would think to use the term "king" to describe the creature.  Oh, well.  Always nice to mince words with you, @EdwinAshworth!

Comment: You obviously missed the 'British Sea Life' card set given away by Brooke Bond Tea about a million years ago. I think the size of the things prompted the 'king' (cf king prawns).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, 1971 was the last time I was in a position to acquire the card set -- was it on offer back then? LOL!  I feel really deprived!  Despite being a Yank, I am, by the way, a Cheltenham Grammar School "Old Boy"!  with two A-levels (Physics & Chemistry) and an O-level pass in Math.